# Can i override path in feature file for a test called from another file

Tags: karate, gherkin

Feature 1: creates a member and then retrieves the value details using GET with the URL: http:localhost:0000/rest/retrieve/**accountHash**

Feature 2: Update Member using POST and assertions using feature 1. http:localhost:0000/rest/update/**accountHash**

Question: I need to override the **accountHash** value from feature 1 with the **accountHash** value generated in feature 2 when feature 1 is called.

Comment: yes. and should be easy. spend some time reading the docs. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue